# What is the site's policy on slang words?

Tags: discussion

Here [in this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/30378/22857), a new user [answered](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/55258/22857) but used the 4 lettered word starting with a 'd' to refer to the male generative organ, which is considered as a slang. I thought of editing the answer to remove the offensive 4-lettered word, but then I thought that it would create a bad precedent (of others covering up application of expletives with the OP bearing no consequences whatsoever) & didn't actually solve the real problem about the usage of expletives. Besides, apart from using the expletive word, the answer was fine in other categories. Currently, no feature exists to flag answers using cuss words. I have seen many people incorporating slang terms into their daily vocabulary & the user may be one of those sort of people, but that can't be considered a valid reason to report somebody. So I would like to what should be done in such cases where slang terms are casually incorporated into answers.

Comment: *..Currently, no feature exists to flag answers using cuss words.* <-- You could use custom mod flag. The answer is full of swear words which we don't entertain. but since they are a new user, as old users, we can help such users by pointing out what they need to improve. But if this goes on; as in said user doesn't stop, feel free to make a custom flag to mod.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Meta FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22194/should-i-edit-a-question-or-answer-with-offensive-content),

> Since the community has awarded you with enough reputation points to edit posts, the community trusts you to do the right thing when you see offensive posts: You should trust your own judgment too, and do what you feel is necessary in the particular situation.

---

My own opinion is that we should edit these out; Hinduism.SE and the Stack Exchange network as a whole are supposed to be academic. That means that language should be fairly formal and we shouldn't really have *any* slang, whether it's vulgar or not.

Even though 'dude' isn't an offensive word, it's still a bit out of place on our site, and future visitors would likely prefer the second option here:

- then shiva told the other dude that he oughta kill the elephant.
- Then, Lord Shiva told the other man to kill the elphant.

So I think the same idea applies in an example more similar to the one you bring up, where the slang word is actually vulgar:

- In the shiva purana, lord shiva touches his d*ck
- There is one scene in the Shiva Purana where Lord Shiva touches his penis/reproductive organ.

Again, the second answer is more clinical and academic, and therefore probably better.

---

I would say that you should edit it out, but the answer itself is kind of poor and reads more like a rant that happens to quote a few scriptures.

You could always flag it for mod attention if you're really unsure.